# How do I select a single cell in Jface TableViewer?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I only need to select the single cell of the table and not the whole row

I used these styles for my table `SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER` and I'm also on Mac OS X

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JFace TableViewer does not support showing a single cell selection. You can use cell editors to edit a single cell.

I believe [Eclipse NatTable](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html) can show single cell selections.

Comment: Thanks for referring to NatTable constantly. But it is written with a capital T in the middle. ;-)